# How to capture output from a command and pass it on to a variable in csh scripting?

Tags: csh, tcsh

I'm trying to capture output of command into variable in csh but its printing empty value to the variable. but if i run same command on terminal its working

```
root_part_id=`gpart show | grep zfs | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for variable assignment in csh is `set variable = value`, so

```
set root_part_id = `gpart show | grep zfs | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Note that awk is quite capable of pattern matching so you could omit the `grep` and use `awk '/zfs/{print $3}'` instead.